# ListView Adapter Displaying Wrong Item

Tags: android, listview, adapter, realm

I am using Realm.io for this project. I create the realm instance in a fragment, and pass the RealmResults to my Adapter. Everyone there works. Cool Beans. I have an edittext which I use to search, which is also within my fragment. It is finding the correct realm objects, which I can see through a Log message on the console.

I know my adapter is getting the correct information.

For example,

```
Object A: Comment=a!
Object B: Comment = b!
Object C: Comment = c
```

If I search for the text "!", it will show Objects A and B in my listview. If i search for the text "b", only object A will be shown. But, the search found the correct object because I can see it in my console. And again, if i search for "c", only object A is shown.

Do you guys have any idea why this would be happening?

Here is the Fragment W/ListView

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        realm = Realm.getInstance(getActivity());
        RealmQuery<MyObject> query = realm.where(MyObject.class);
        mItems = query.findAll();
        realm.setAutoRefresh(true);
        adapter = new MyObjectAdapter(getActivity(), mItems,false,
                "fonts/Verdana.ttf");
        realm.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChange() {
            }
        });





        realm.commitTransaction();

        // initialize and set the list adapter
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.log_entry_fragment, container,false);

        editsearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);


        editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                adapter.updateRealmResults(mItems);
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int     count,int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             /* Message message = buildMessage(WorkerHandler.SEARCH, s);
               workerThread.workerHandler.sendMessage(message);
               Log.d("CharSeq11111111", s.toString());*/

               RealmQuery<MyObject> realmQuery= realm.where(MyObject.class);
                realmQuery.contains("comment", s.toString());
                mItems = realmQuery.findAll();
                Log.d("SecondmItems", ""+mItems.toString());





            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Here is the Adapter:

```
 public class MyObjectAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<MyObject> implements ListAdapter{
        RealmResults<MyObject> objects;
        Typeface tf;
        public Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ViewHolder aViewHolder;
        bViewHolder bViewHolder;
        cViewHolder cViewHolder;
        Realm realm;

        public MyObjectAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<MyObject> realmResults,
                               boolean automaticUpdate, String FONT) {
            super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
            this.context = context;
            objects = realmResults;
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), FONT);

        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount()

        {

            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position)

        {
            return realmResults.get(position).getType();
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {


            return realmResults.size();
        }
        public void updateList(RealmResults<MyObject> newList){
            this.realmResults = newList;
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public MyObject getItem(int position)
        {
            return realmResults.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)

        {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {

            MyObject listViewItem = realmResults.get(position);
            int listViewItemType = listViewItem.getType();
            aViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            bViewHolder = new bViewHolder();
            cViewHolder = new cViewHolder();
            if(convertView == null) {
                inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                MyObject item =  getItem(position);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a_card_listview_item, parent, false);
                    /*Inflate the correct view for the type of object we're currently working with. Each
                    object has its own specific XML file, and hence needs to be inflated based on type.
                     */

                    if(listViewItemType == 1){
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.a_card_listview_item, parent, false);
                    }
                    else if(listViewItemType == 0){
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.b_journal_listview_item, parent, false);
                    }
                    else if(listViewItemType == 2){
                        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.c_journal_listview_item, parent, false);
                    }

                    //Set the background for the view. Every other object will alternate in colors.
                    if(position%2 == 0){
                        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.largertailtesttwo);
                    }
                    else {
                        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.largertailtest);
                    }


               /* Set Views and View Content Here */

            } else {
                // recycle the already inflated view
                //aViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            return convertView;
        }


        private static class ViewHolder {

            TextView category;
            TextView description;
            TextView date;
            TextView privacy;
            TextView minutes;
            TextView hours;
            TextView client;
        }
        private static class bViewHolder {
            TextView bCategory;
            TextView privacy;
            TextView bType;
            TextView bJoinedBy;
            RatingBar bStarLevel;
            TextView bDescription;
            TextView bDate;
            TextView typeCategory;


        }
        private static class cViewHolder {
            TextView cCategory;
            TextView privacy;
            TextView cType;
            TextView cJoinedBy;
            RatingBar cStarLevel;
            TextView cDescription;
            TextView cDate;
            TextView cTypeCategory;


        }
    }
```

EDIT: Thanks to user @Rami! He pointed out that using "If (ConvertView==null)" doesn't work correctly for the way I am inflating my views. I removed the if/else in there, and it seems to work perfectly fine now!

Awesome!

Comment: i think `getViewTypeCount` method will return `2` instead of `1`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K That throws an Index out of bounds error

Comment: but List have 3 type of layout a,b,c but getViewTypeCount returning only 1

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I set the ViewType using a variable from within the Objects. For Example, Object A has a "ListViewItemType", and I inflate the view based on that.

Comment: Try to remove `if(convertView == null)` (to inflate a new layout each time), i think the way you manage your types doesn't work perfectly with ListView recycling mechanism.

Comment: @Rami That worked perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!  I appreciate your help too, prosper. I'll edit my post to help others out too.

Comment: Glad for you. That fix your problem but this is not the right way to manage ListView items type, see this example: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296 (**Section:** *Different list items’ layouts*)